# How to read Parquet files from S3 Ceph in Java using Flink 1.16.0 Table API?

Tags: java, amazon-s3, apache-flink, parquet, flink-table-api

I am trying to read Parquet files from S3 Ceph in Java using flink 1.16.0 and Table API FileSystem connector but encountering the following error:

`java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/conf/Configuration`

As written in Flink’s documentation, I used the following dependencies in my pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
  <artifactId>flink-parquet</artifactId>
  <version>1.16.0</version>
</dependency>
```

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
  <artifactId>flink-connector-files</artifactId>
  <version>1.16.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Following the mentioned error I tried to add some Hadoop dependencies in order to resolve this exception but it still not working and looks like the solution should be simpler.

Has anyone encountered a similar problem?

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: In my case I fixed a similar problem by putting flink-shaded-hadoop-2-uber-2.8.3-10.0 somewhere in my classpath.

Comment: Thank you David. I tried that and got another exception which I’ve seen before: org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem not found. I point out that I have the s3-fs-hadoop dependency in my plugins folder.

Comment: The S3 Hadoop dependency should be in its own folder inside the plugins folder